# How do you calculate the partition function on a manifold-with-corners in extended TQFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topology, topological-field-theory, category-theory, topological-defects

In Atiyah's formulation, a Topological Quantum Field Theory (TQFT), is a functor $Z:d\text{Bord}\to\text{Hilb}$. That is, $Z$ assigns:

\begin{align}
\text{Closed compact $(d-1)$-manifolds} &\to \text{f.d. Hilbert spaces} \\
\text{$d$-dimensional bordisms between manifolds} &\to \text{Unitary maps between corresponding Hilbert spaces}
\end{align}

To implement locality, further structure should be added, leading to the notion of an *extended* TQFT. An extended TQFT is supposed to assign "stuff" (i.e. categories) to manifolds of each codimension, possibly with boundaries and corners. To illustrate this, take $d=2$. In Atiyah's TQFT, we can compute things like the following:
[image]

In an extended TQFT, we can compute all the above, but in addition we should now be able compute things like: [image]

I used filled-in and empty points to denote incoming and outgoing. Note that a manifold gets assigned to an object in the category corresponding to its boundary: $Z(M)\in Z(\partial M)$. So for example, Fig 2a is some object in the category $Z(\bullet)\otimes Z(\circ)$. Fig 2c is meant to show a bordism between two line segments, which is an example of a bordism-between-bordisms, and has corners.

Now, given some physical theory -- for example Chern-Simons in 3D, or open-closed strings in 2D, or perhaps a 2D gauge theory with action like $\int F$ -- how do we actually calculate the value of diagrams like Fig 2c? I'm unfamiliar with calculating partition functions on manifolds with corners!

I'd be satisfied with an answer that gives an concrete example (even if it's simple) of a TQFT where we know how to evaluate Fig 2c.

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4673511/11127